# `select` in dplyr is not working inside the function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

could you please tell me what's wrong with this function?

```
sum_it_up <- function(x){
    dplyr::select(x)|>
    dplyr::group_by(x)|>
    dplyr::summarize(
    count = sum(x)
)
}

-------------------------------------------------
So i used this function:
```

`sum_it_all <- function(ds, x){`
`select(ds, x)|>`
`dplyr::group_by(`
 `x`
`) |>`
`dplyr::summarize(`
`n = n()`
`)`
`}`

```
My variable is categorical:
`x = ("Yes, "No", "Not known", "Yes", "Yes", "No")`

I am getting the following error:
```

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `Yes`, `Yes`, `No`, `Yes`, `Yes`, etc. don't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

```
What you guys suggest @Ian Campbell @pax
```

Comment: You need to pass the dataframe to the function too. Like `function(dataframe,variable){select(dataframe,variable)|> ...` Then pass `variable` as a string, like `"variable"`.

Comment: I would recommend to extend this function with checks, e.g. `stopifnot(is.factor(x))` if you are planning to use it frequently, ...

Comment: If you're planning on using this function in a pipe, as in `somedata |> sum_it_up(myvar)`, then you likely need to read through [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: Thanks guys, I am not using the function in a pipe. Just on a simple dataset where I need to summarize a lot of variables. Not working so far. I will try just a bit more and if it does not work I will state the problem here.

Comment: Guys could you please see the edits I made and comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing ". Additionally, x should be passed in as a string, as per comments.

Count of entries within column x of dataframe ds:

```
library(dplyr)

sum_it_all <- function(ds, x) {
  select(ds, x) |>
    dplyr::group_by(x) |>
    dplyr::summarize(n = n())
}
x <- c("Yes", "No", "Not known", "Yes", "Yes", "No")
y <- runif(length(x))

sum_it_all(tibble(x, y), "x")
```